# Determining Core Location provider type (Cell or wi-fi)?

Tags: iphone, ios, location, provider

I'm trying to determine the type of location provider.

GPS is easy to detect with verticalAccuracy >= 0, but I'd also like to figure out if cell triangulation or wifi is being used.

I've read that the order of accuracy is GPS, cell, wifi. If so, can we assume iOS will always attempt to get locations in this order? This may give a clue based on network reachability.

Thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: And why do you need this? Maybe you can solve a problem without this info?

Comment: I wouldn't have asked otherwise, Socrates. ;)

Comment: You can try to guess provider type from accuracy, that is returned with every location update. But it's only guessing.